# Acer aspire 3680

Tags: hardware-failure

I put stikers on my laptop so i wanted to remove them.
So i first took out my laptop battery.
-i took a dry tool and removed the stickers.
-And i took a wet towel and rubbed it outside.
-Then a little water gon on the keyboard but i quckly rubbed it off.
-i put the battery back and it was fine.
-the next day when i switched it on it sad OPERATING SYSTEM NOT FOUND.
-So turnded it off and took out then battery then put it back and switched it on again and a strange sound came out of the laptop but it still booted on.
But after a few minites it turned off and displayed a massage
PXE-MOF MEDIA TEST FAILURE CHECK CABLE
PXE-MOF EXITING PXE ROM
OPERATING SYSTEM NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not made any changes to the BIOS, it appears that either your hard drive is dead, or your operating system has been corrupted by a virus.

Consider getting the drive replaced/OS reinstalled.